# Credit card validator in Python 3.7.1

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge, checksum

I am doing some projects so I can teach myself programming. The one that I finished states:
"Credit Card Validator - Takes in a credit card number from a common credit card vendor  and validates it to make sure that it is a valid number (look into how credit cards use a checksum)."
Would be glad if i can get a constructive feedback on this one.

```
import sys

cardnumb_input = input('Enter your credit card number: ')


def list_tweak():
    try:
        cardnumb = [int(i) for i in cardnumb_input]
        cardnumb[0::2] = [x * 2 for x in cardnumb[0::2]]
        cardnumb = [str(i) for i in cardnumb]
        cardnumb = list(''.join(cardnumb))
        cardnumb = [int(i) for i in cardnumb]
        return cardnumb

    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter only number in format: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
        sys.exit(1)


def valid_or_not():
    total = sum(list_tweak())
    if total % 10 != 0:
        print('It seems that this credit card number is not valid.')
    else:
        print('This credit card number is valid. ')


valid_or_not()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## What should the type signature of these functions be?

I would really separate the IO from data. In addition, I would display data that you already have. I would not have `valid_or_not` print stuff out. Instead I would have it *return* a *value*. But what value?

Furthermore, don't read global variables. `valid_or_not` and `list_tweak` should take paramters.

We'll get to printing stuff in the end.

## What do you want to do with an invalid credit card number?

You are both throwing an error, and also printing out whether it is a valid card number. I would say there is a couple ways to go, but I prefer this approach:

> Return an [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) that ends up being either: `VALID`, `INVALID_CHECKSUM`, or `INVALID_FORMAT`. Instead of doing printing.

## Rework the flow of `valid_or_not`.

Consider reworking `valid_or_not` to do the following:

1. Check to see if the format is valid, and return `INVALID_FORMAT` if it is not.
2. The run `list_tweak`, but don't do `try`-`except` on it, return either `INVALID_CHECKSUM` or `VALID` depending on `list_tweak`.

## Naming.

I am not sure what `list_tweak` means, but I am assuming only because I've seen this problem show up time and time again that it is the Luhn algorithm. Name it something appropriate like `luhn_checksum`.

## IO

So what should we really be doing for input? First we should have a [`main` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158605/667648) (see the link for more information why. Thus we get:

```
def main():
    cardnumber = input('Enter your credit card number: ')
    print(valid_or_not(cardnumber))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

See all the data is manipulated in `valid_or_not` which is *then* displayed, instead of displaying information withing `valid_or_not`).